# Multiprocessing for a single command in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
processes = cpu_count()
pool = Pool(processes)

pool.map(print("Hello, world!"))
```

This gives the error: `TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'`. This seems to go for other parallellization packages as well (such as `concurrent.futures`). They demand that a defined function is applied to an iterable. But how can a single command be forced to use more than one cpu core?

Let's say that instead of `print("Hello, world!")` above, there was a command to run a topic model, or calculate Pi or whatever: Can that process be sped up by parallelization? Or is it even the fact that 100% cpu load on 1 out of, say, 16 cores can still mean that the entire processing power of the machine is used?

Comment: [Speculative execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) is one general way to parallelise commands/functions, but it doesn't scale to complex functions.

Comment: Your current error is just due to how map works, you need to feed it a function and an iterable.

Comment: "Or is it even the fact that 100% cpu load on 1 out of, say, 16 cores can still mean that the entire processing power of the machine is used?" No, it's not used. But your example is insufficient to suggest the correct approach because it is not CPU-intensive and is not iterable. If you wanted to pass each value to a Pi function then you could use `NumPy` to duck under the GIL. You can't just throw processors at problems in Python because Processes come with plenty of overhead and IPC issues.

Comment: You need to divide the work (your algorithm) you want to parallelize into parts which can be processed independently by different worker-processes. Not every problem is suited for that. That's what distinguishes an "embarrassingly parallel problem" from an "inherently sequential problem".